# LightTable Set on-change inline eval for javascript

Tags: javascript, lighttable

How can I set on-change behavior in light table to be inline evaluation for JavaScript ?

The auto-complete in user settings behavior page has appended

`((:lt.objs.editor/on-change ))`

but I need to know how to make light table do on-change inline evaluation from this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
[:editor.javascript :lt.objs.editor/on-change :eval-editor]
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I've stopped using lightable from a while, but I'll try to check your answer ASAP, and if valid I'll accept it.